# Getting and Setting the width of an element with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a ul list element that varies in width with the text inside it, that changes regularly. Now I want to set the width of the ul list to the width of the first list element, which is text that could change. I want to 'get' the width of the first list item(#item1) and 'set' the width of the ul list (#myList) to that width of the first list item just mentioned. I tried the following code but it does not work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var width = document.getElementById('item1').offsetWidth;
  document.getElementById('myList').style.width = width;
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="myList">
  <li id="item1">text1</li>
  <li>text2</li>
  <li>text3</li>
</ul>
```

Any suggestions? I would prefer to Not use jquery, but pure javascript...

Thanks!

Comment: style.width needs units, you could use = width+"px"; or just lose the style and use ('item1').width

Comment: Also, if you haven't done so, put the script element after the html

Comment: The width of the `li` spans the width of the `ul` Do you want to know how much width the actual text takes up?

Comment: `ul {display:inline-block}` will "fit to contents" if that's what your after

Comment: What happens if subsequent list items are wider? Do you want them to be cutoff?

Comment: @Mike, i can't believe I forgot that. Thanks a lot! works like a charm.

Comment: @ Esailija: After the whole body element or just after the html elements in question here?

Comment: @ j08691: No, they are text that is justified. they just move to the next line...

Comment: @Alex K.: Yes but the list items below the first one(#item1) is longer than #item 1, so the ul list will span with them, and not the first one...

Answer (score 0):

Use this.. In here I have assumed that the ul element is #ul and list element is #list

```
 var liWidth=document.querySelector('#list').clientWidth;

 // make the width of ul same
 document.querySelector('#ul').style.width=liWidth+'px';
```

That should workk.. And be sure to create element before loading JavaScript or it will throw error that it cannot find style property of null